# How to get old value select option after submit blade laravel

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

this is the code and when i submit form why i can't selected old data?

```
<select class="form-control" name="dateRestrict">
    <option value="" {{ old('dateRestrict') == "" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Random Time</option>
    <option value="d1" {{ old('dateRestrict') == "d1" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Yesterday</option>
    <option value="w" {{ old('dateRestrict') == "w" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Last Week</option>
    <option value="m" {{ old('dateRestrict') == "m" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Last Month</option>
    <option value="y"{{ old('dateRestrict') == "y" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Last Year</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You may be missing `->withInput()` in the controller, depending on how you are validating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller

```
if(isset($request->dateRestrict)){
    $dateRestrict=$request->dateRestrict;
}
return view('view-name',compact('dateRestrict');
```

**Blade.php**

```
<select class="form-control" name="dateRestrict">
         <option value="" @if(isset($dateRestrict) && $dateRestrict==""){{"selected"}} @endif >Random Time</option>
         <option value="d1" @if(isset($dateRestrict) && $dateRestrict=="d1"){{"selected"}} @endif >Yesterday</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You are always Welcome